# Why is drag neglected while dealing with kinematic problems?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, drag, error-analysis, approximations

1. Why is drag neglected while dealing with kinematic problems?

While dealing with problems related to finding velocity, acceleration and other kinematic problems, it is mentioned to "neglect drag".

2. If we find velocity or acceleration of a body neglecting drag, to how much extent does the answer become wrong, i.e what is the percentage error of the answer?

Comment: It's generally left out at first to simplify things. Algebra can be used with kinematics to do drag-less calculations, but calculus is needed for some drag problems.

Comment: The percentage error depends on the speed of the moving object, the amount of area in contact with the moving object, so it's impossible to give a general answer. http://physics.info/drag/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simplification.**

There are different formulas that are used to calculate drag at various speed regimes. The problem is, they are all of the form
$$F\propto v^n$$
where $n=1$ or $2$. This means that
$$a\propto v^n$$
which in turn means that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\propto \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^n$$
You need calculus to solve this, instead of simple algebra.

Aside from "it's hard", why do we want to ignore drag? Well, in most kinematics problems, it's not too important. This animation shows the differences in the path of a projectile launched at 70 degrees when accounting for no drag (black), Stokes (low Reynolds number/low velocity) drag (blue), and drag in a Newtonian fluid (green). Notice how there isn't much of a difference between the path of the object with no drag and the path of the object with Stokes drag for short periods of time:

[image]

<sup>From Wikipedia user AllenMcC., under the [Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en).</sup>

At lower angles and lower speeds, there isn't much of a difference. The same goes for the approximation of the acceleration due to gravity as $g$. While, in reality, $\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}y}\neq 0$, we approximate it like that because we deal with motion over small intervals.

Comment: As currently written you are saying "because it's hard". The other part of the answer is "and usually you can ignore it because..." - worth adding?

Comment: @Floris I guess so. I'll add that in.

Comment: @Floris I added a short section to that affect.